# c++ pthread_t: how can I ensure that it has started?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I haven't worked with threads a lot, but wondering how I can ensure that a thread has started (it will run until the system shuts down, I'm just using the default attributes on create).

I've googled this, but there's nothing for threads that won't terminate, have a thread_join waiting for them - I don't need or want to wait for it to terminate.

```
pthread_attr_t attr = { 0 };
pthread_t TID = 0;
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
if (!pthread_create(&TID, &attrSys, &threadProcess, NULL))
    std::cout << "Error on thread create." << std::endl;
```

Is that enough to guarantee that the thread has actually started? I've looked at TID.joinable (which my compiler complained about), trying pthread_kill and looking for an error (but that was discounted due to the unreliability of the thread id in some cases).

Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that pthreads is a POSIX thing, not a C++ thing. The C++ standard doesn't say anything about how this code should work.

Comment: Yes, your code starts a thread. And it will run until it exits, or your process terminates. Why do you think that it doesn't run?

Comment: 1) use `std::thread` not posix threads. 2) you are using threads: be very, very afraid. 3) you are using threads: you have bugs (unless you are one of a very small group of experts). 4) you don't yet know what pain those threads will cause you down the line. - threads are *hard* to get correct.

Comment: True. But threads are 1) necessary, 2) fast and 3) fun :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: you overdramatize a little bit. Threads + mutexes are not that hard. What's hard is lockless programming.

Comment: @PeteBecker Absolutely right - I guess the intent was how to check in c++.

Comment: @geza I do prints, etc, it always runs, but just wanted to doubly be sure that the rest of the code waits at least until the thread is running.

Comment: At all - Thanks for good input!

Comment: @campana: I don't know what you mean. If a thread still runs, and your process exists (returns from main), all your threads will be destroyed (won't be waited until they exit)

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of `pthread_create` :

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

`pthread_create` returns an `<errno.h>` code :

On success, `pthread_create()` returns `0;` on error, it returns an `error`
       number, and the contents of `*thread` are undefined.